# Microsoft CA: Where does user private key come from?

Tags: security, authentication, certificate

Sorry, that it isn't exactly programming question, but it is also interest.
So my question is: Where does user private key comes from?
Whether it comes in key-pair together with public key in certificate that is generated in CA, or it is generated in client OS, when only thumb-print, public key and so on comes from CA?

Thank you for ahead.

Comment: If you feel the need to start a question on SO with "Sorry, that it isn't exactly programming question", then you may want to rethink....

Comment: What does this have to do with Microsoft?

Answer (score 1):

Private and public keys are mathematically linked. The generation process gets you **both**, **always**; one is called private (you keep it safe), one is called public (you can give it to anyone)
The link is hard to find, so knowing one of them does not help in finding the other one.

When you sign something, you need your private key. When people want to check the signature, they need your public key.

When you encrypt something, you need the public key of the recipient. Only he will able to decrypt because this requires the private key.

So, at the beginning, you have both in a file and you can extract the public key for distribution (or put it in a certificate if you want other people to trust it).

Edit: I started a comment but it was too long, so here it is:

Each security libray has its own tools that implement the necessary math to build the correct public/private pair. OpenSSL comes with a command line tool, with which you can create your own CA, create certificate requests and certificates. Windows Server has Certificate Services with analogous features. .NET has the sn (sn = strong name) tool that creates files (with snk extension) with public/private keys (used to sign a DLL). Visual Studio has a GUI front-end for creating snk files. There are of course tools in the Java world (one is called keystore if I am not mistaken) and on Mac OS X.
When you create certificates yourself, they are called 'self-signed' and are not trusted by the rest of the world.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I still didn't understand:
where from I get this key pair? Whether it comes from CA server, or it generated by User OS or DC when user created. In other words, whether I get this pair by default from my OS without submit query for certificate from CA?

Answer (score 0):

The keys usually (and should) come from the client, so the private key can be kept private. There are cases where you get a PFX-file provided but then there is not trust that nobody else has access to the private key.

Talking about Windows there is so called `Providers` that can generate keys (beside other cryptographic operations). There is the [old (CSP/CAPI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccertenroll/cryptoapi-cryptographic-service-providers) version and the [newer (CNG)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccertenroll/cng-key-storage-providers) ones. Beside the ability to generate and store keys on the machine an it's hard drive, there are some which allow the key to be stored on a smart card or for instance an USB token or even a hardware security module (HSM) - 3rd parties provide implementations for the providers too.

Beside the provider which are build in there are of curse other tools and software that can generate keys like OpenSSL.

So what happens after the keys are generated - just top fulfill the story.

A certificate request (basically the public key and some attributes like the subject name and others) is **signed with the private key** and submitted to a certificate authority (CA). The CA uses its own certificate (along with the private key) to **sign the attributes and the public key** from the request. The result is called a certificate.